# Cypress: Availability check before Test Case run

Tags: cypress

i would like to check (in before) if the homepage is online. If it is online, the Test steps (it()) have to be run.
If the homepage is offline, the test case have to terminate, before the it() run.

```
describe('check Homepage', () => {

before(() => {

    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('.welcomeText').then((text) => {
        
        if(text.text() !== 'Welcome to x'){
           //terminate Test Case
        }
  })
})

it('check a', () => {
})

it('check b', () => {
})

it('check c', () => {
})
```

})

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a situation when your environment is not in good status for all your tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can just let it fail :)

But the check you want can be done with `cy.request()`

```js
// NOTE must be function

function checkHomepage() {
  const homepageUrl = Cypress.config('baseUrl')
  cy.request({
    url: homepageUrl,
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {     // homepage is offline   
      this.skip()                            // skip the test
    }
  })
}

beforeEach(checkHomepage)
```

You could also take a proactive approach and retry until the homepage is accessable

```js
function checkHomepage() {
  const homepageUrl = Cypress.config('baseUrl')
  cy.request({
    url: homepageUrl,
    retryOnStatusCodeFailure: true,
    retryOnNetworkFailure: true
  })
}

beforeEach(checkHomepage)
```